# How to read data from CGI webpage using Python?

Tags: python, cgi

I have data that is stored in a server in a CGI formatted file. My data looks like this:

```
netdev = {
  'WIRED': { d1:0x14c1892, d2:0x86d33c6 }
 ,'BRIDGE': { d1:0x1415384, d2:0x85cb08a }
 ,'WIRELESS0': { d1:0x0, d2:0x0 }
 ,'WIRELESS1': { d1:0x0, d2:0x0 }
}
```

**NOTE:** this is a converted version of the data (what you see here is plain text version that firefox created as firefox doesn't recognize the encoding of the data itself)

And this is how the html looks like of the webpage:
[image]

by using `document.characterSet` in console of browser I got `windows-1252` as encoding

But I can't figure out how to fetch this data using python and read from it the required values.

I tried to do that using `requests` library, but somehow it doesn't return any text or content in the response body (while the response status is 200).

I also tried this:

```
r = requests.post(URL)
r.encoding = 'windows-1252'
print(r.text)
```

but it still doesn't return the required data.

Comment: could u provide the URL ?

Comment: I have the server locally, it is not on the internet

Comment: No worries. Download the html and post it on your github. We can access it this way. When asking questions, dont forget to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share any code/data as text in the post itself, not as images. I’m no expert on the subject, but shouldn’t you be using a GET request, instead of a POST? I’m also not sure I understand the encoding issue, and how it relates to the rest of your post.

Comment: first you should use `get()` instead of `post()` - if it is still doesn't work then you may have to uses DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox` (tab "network") to see headers, cookies, etc. used in request and then use them too. If page normally need to login then your screen will have to also login.